# 2checkout test payment simulation

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, 2checkout

In a **php** application of mine, **I am looking for help on how to simulate test payment  with https://www.2checkout.com/.**  I have experience with test payment for **Paypal sandbox using developer account**. But in here 2checkout I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With 2Checkout, you can place a demo sale by changing your demo account setting to "On" on the Site Management page in your 2Checkout account. Once this is set, you will see a message at the top of the checkout page stating that this is a demo sale. If your account is currently being used for live sales, you can place a demo sale by changing your demo account setting to "Parameter" and then pass in an additional "demo" parameter with a value of "Y". This way your live sales will not be interrupted.

Example:

https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/spurchase?sid=1303908&mode=2CO&li_0_type=product&li_0_price=1.00&li_0_quantity=1&li_0_name=Example+Product+Name&demo=Y

You should note that when placing demo sales the MD5 hash returned by 2Checkout is intentionally broken by computing the hash with a 1 for the order number so if you are checking against the hash your return script needs to handle this change.

Example:

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['demo'] == 'Y') 
{
    $order_number = 1;
}
else
{
    $order_number = $_REQUEST['order_number'];
}

$compare_string = $_REQUEST['secret_word'] . $_REQUEST['sid'] . $order_number . $_REQUEST['total'];
$compare_hash1 = strtoupper(md5($compare_string));
$compare_hash2 = $_REQUEST['key'];

if ($compare_hash1 != $compare_hash2)
{
    echo "Hash Mismatch";
}
else
{
    echo "Hash Matched";
}
```

INS messages are not sent on demo sales so if you are also utilizing the Instant Notification Service (INS), you can use the [INS testing tool](http://developers.2checkout.com/inss) to simulate the INS messages you are listening for.

Please feel free to also contact techsupport@2checkout.com if you need assistance with testing your integration.

Comment: inss simulator is not working anymore , sandbox tool is not working on all notification messages , tech support is just apologizing for inconviences , meanwhile we cannot automate our system due to lack of testing tools.is there any useful solution you can provide where i can actually test all webhooks?

Comment: Error 404 on IPN testing tool link